# Downloading a csv file in angular from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, csv, file, download

I am having an issue to download a csv file which is located on the server side.

My function in the NodeJS API:

```
router.get('/downloadCsv/', (req,res) => {
    const projectId = req.query.projectId;
    const pathCsv = 'searchResults/project_' + projectId + '/OutputsCsv/';
    const fileName = req.query.fileName;
    const fullPath = pathCsv + fileName
    const file = fs.readFileSync(fullPath)
  
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.attachment(fileName)
    res.status(200).send({file})
    
})
```

My function in my Angular 11 component

```
download() {
    const pathCsv = 'searchResults/project_' + this.projectId + '/OutputsCsv/';
    const fileName = 'project_' + this.projectId + '_output_datas.csv';
    const fullPath = pathCsv + fileName

    this.searchService.downloadCsv(this.projectId, fileName).subscribe((buffer) => {
 
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8' });

    fileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName);

    }), (error: any) => console.log('Error downloading the file'),
    () => console.info('File downloaded successfully');
  }
```

In the service :

```
public downloadCsv(projectId, fileName){
    let params = new HttpParams().set("projectId", projectId).set("fileName", fileName);
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/search/downloadCsv`, {params});
 }
```

The datas in the new downloaded csv file is just :

[Object Object]

How can I get the same datas than the original file?

Comment: seems like the problem is in the creation of the file. If you open the file with a text editor can you see the contents, and it is structured as a csv?

Answer (score 0):

In your service you have to specify the response type for a file, in this case blob:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/search/downloadCsv`, {params},{responseType: 'blob', accept: 'text/csv'})
```